# C Shell hanging when dealing with piping

Tags: c, pipe, fork, exec, dup

I'm working on a C shell and am having trouble with getting an arbitrary amount of pipes to work.  When I run the shell, it hangs on any piping.  For some reason, when I do `ls -la | sort`, it hangs on the sort until I enter stuff and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.  I know it has something to do with a pipe not closing, but the print statements show that pipes 3,4,5 all get closed in both the parent and child.  I've been at this for a few hours and don't know why this doesn't work.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Original Code:

```
char *current_command;
current_command = strtok_r(cmdline_copy, "|", &cmdline_copy);
char *commands[100][MAX_ARGS]; //Max 100 piped commands with each having MAX_ARGS arguments
int i = 0;
while (current_command != NULL) { //Go through each command and add it to the array
    char *copy = malloc(strlen(current_command)*sizeof(char)); //Copy of curretn command
    strcpy(copy, current_command);
    char *args_t[MAX_ARGS];
    int nargs_t = get_args(copy, args_t);
    memcpy(commands[i], args_t, sizeof(args_t)*nargs_t); //Copy the command and it's arguments to the 2d array
    i++;
    current_command = strtok_r(NULL, "|\n", &cmdline_copy); //Use reentrant version of strtok to prevent fighting with get_args function
}
int fd[2*(i-1)]; //Set up the pipes i.e fd[0,1] is first pipe, fd[1,2] second pipe, etc.
for (int j = 0; j < i*2; j+=2) {
    pipe(fd+j);
}
//Here is where we do the commands
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    pid = fork(); //Fork
    if (pid == 0) { //Child process
        if (j == 0) { //First process
            printf("Child Closed %d\n", fd[0]);
            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1], fileno(stdout));
        }
        else if (j == i -1) { //Last process
            dup2(fd[j], fileno(stdin));
            printf("Child closed %d\n", fd[j]);
            printf("Child closed %d\n", fd[j+1]);
            close(fd[j+1]);
            close(fd[j]);
        }
        else { //Middle processes
            dup2(fd[j], fileno(stdin));
            dup2(fd[j+1], fileno(stdout));
            printf("Child closed %d\n", fd[j]);
            close(fd[j]);
        }
        execvp(commands[j][0], commands[j]);
    }
    else if (pid > 0) { //Parent
        printf("Parent closed %d\n", fd[j]);
        close(fd[j]);
        printf("Parent closed %d\n", fd[j+1]);
        close(fd[j+1]);
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0); //Wait for the process
    }
    else {
        perror("Error with fork");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Final Code:

```
char *current_command;
current_command = strtok_r(cmdline_copy, "|", &cmdline_copy);
char *commands[100][MAX_ARGS]; //Max 100 piped commands with each having MAX_ARGS arguments
int command_count = 0;
while (current_command != NULL) { //Go through each command and add it to the array
   char *copy = malloc(strlen(current_command)*sizeof(char)); //Copy of curretn command because get_args uses strtok
   strcpy(copy, current_command);
   char *args_t[MAX_ARGS];
   int nargs_t = get_args(copy, args_t);
   memcpy(commands[command_count], args_t, sizeof(args_t)*nargs_t); //Copy the command and it's arguments to the 2d array
   command_count++;
   current_command = strtok_r(NULL, "|\n", &cmdline_copy); //Use reentrant version of strtok to prevent fighting with get_args function
}
int fd[command_count*2-1];
pid_t pids[command_count];
for (int j = 0; j < command_count*2; j+=2) { //Open up a pair of pipes for every command
   pipe(fd+j);
}
for (int j = 0; j < command_count; j++) {
   pids[j] = fork();
   if (pids[j] == 0) { //Child process
      if (j == 0) { //Duplicate only stdout pipe for first pipe
         dup2(fd[1], fileno(stdout));
      }
      else if (j == (command_count-1)) { //Duplicate only stdin for last pipe
         up2(fd[2*(command_count-1)-2], fileno(stdin));
      }
      else { //Duplicate both stdin and stdout
         dup2(fd[2*(j-1)], fileno(stdin));
         dup2(fd[2*j+1], fileno(stdout));
      }
      for (int k = 0; k < j*2; k++) { //Close all fds
         close(fd[k]);
      }
      execvp(commands[j][0], commands[j]); //Exec the command
   }
   else if (pids[j] < 0) {
      perror("Error forking");
   }
}
for (int k = 0; k < command_count*2; k++) { //Parent closes all fds
   close(fd[k]);
}
waitpid(pids[command_count-1], NULL, 0); //Wait for only the last process;
```

Comment: There's something that must be wrong with the `fd` array and the two `for` loops : the first loop uses `i*2` elements in `fd` but the secong loop uses only `i+1` elements. At least the second loop should have a `j+=2` increment. Sadly have no time now to look further now, it is just a clue,

Comment: Isn't that because a pipe has 2 ends? For 2 commands you have 4 pipes, 2 in 2 out, and then the second for loop goes through the two commands.

Comment: Up to a point, it is OK to edit the question.  Once you start to get answers, you should be cautious about changing the question in a way which invalidates the answers.  Typically, that might mean leaving the original code alone from there on (unless you fix non-critical typos or similar), but add new/revised code as an edit.  You should have some version of the flawed code on display — it is OK to add the working code too, but not instead, with suitable annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the children (or, in this case, in the parent).

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`

In your code, you create all the pipes before you fork any children; therefore, each child needs to close all the pipe file descriptors after duplicating the one or two that it is going to use for input or output.

The parent process must also close all the pipe descriptors.

Also, the parent should not wait for children to complete until after launching all the children. In general, children will block with full pipe buffers if you make them run sequentially. You also defeat the benefits of parallelism.  Note, however, that the parent must keep the pipes open until it has launched all the children — it must not close them after it launches each child.

For your code, the outline operation should be:

- Create N pipes
- For each of N (or N+1) children:

  1. Fork.
  2. Child duplicates standard input and output pipes
  3. Child closes *all* of the pipe file descriptors
  4. Child executes process (and reports error and exits if it fails)
  5. Parent records child PID.
  6. Parent goes on to next iteration; no waiting, no closing.
- Parent now closes N pipes.
- Parent now waits for the appropriate children to die.

There are other ways of organizing this, of greater or lesser complexity.  The alternatives typically avoid opening all the pipes up front, which reduces the number of pipes to be closed.

'Appropriate children' means there are various ways of deciding when a pipeline (sequence of commands connected by pipes) is 'done'.

- One option is to wait for the last command in the sequence to exit.  This has advantages — and is the traditional way to do it.  Another advantage is that the parent process can launch the last child; the child can launch its predecessor in the pipeline, back to the first process in the pipeline.  In this scenario, the parent never creates a pipe, so it doesn't have to close any pipes.  It also only has one child to wait for; the other processes in the pipeline are descendents of the one child.
- Another option is to wait for all the processes to die<sup>(1)</sup>.  This is more or less what Bash does.  This allows Bash to know the exit status of each element of the pipeline; the alternative does not permit that — which is relevant to `set -o pipefail` and the `PIPEFAIL` array.

> Can you help me understand why the `dup2` statement for the middle pipes is `dup2(fd[(2*j)+1], fileno(stdout))` and `dup2(fd[2*(j-1)], fileno(stdin))`? I got it off Google and it works, but I'm unsure why.

- `fileno(stdout)` is `1`.
- `fileno(stdin)` is `0`.
- The read end of a pipe is file descriptor 0 (analogous to standard input).
- The write end of a pipe is file descriptor 1 (analogous to standard output).
- You have an array `int fd[2*N];` for some value of N > 1, and you get a pair of file descriptors for each pipe.
- For an integer `k`, `fd[k*2+0]` is the read descriptor of a pipe, and `fd[k*2+1]` is the read descriptor.
- When `j` is neither 0 nor (N-1), you want it to read from the previous pipe and to write to its pipe:

  - `fd[(2*j)+1]` is the write descriptor of pipe `j` — which gets connected to `stdout`.
  - `fd[2*(j-1)]` is the read descriptor of pipe `j-1` — which gets connected to `stdin`.
- So, the two `dup2()` calls connect the the correct pipe file descriptors to standard input and standard output of process `j` in the pipeline.

---

<sup>(1)</sup>
There can be obscure scenarios where this leaves the parent hung indefinitely.  I emphasize *obscure*; it requires something like a process that hangs around as a daemon without forking.

Comment: I commented out the wait statement and closed all file descriptors (see edit).  Now it doesn't hang, but it doesn't output anything either.

Comment: See updated answer.  In your updated code, it seems that the parent closes the pipes inside the child-launching loop.  That's the wrong place.

Comment: Just to be clear, is it N pipes with 1 in 1 out for a total of N*2? Or just N?

Comment: One pipe has two file descriptors; N pipes have 2N file descriptors.  When the parent closes N pipes, it closes 2N file descriptors.  When the child closes all the pipe file descriptors, it closes 2N file descriptors.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it.  Can you help me understand though why the dup2 statement for the middle pipes is `fd[(2*j)+1], fileno(stdout)` and `fd[2*(j-1)], fileno(stdin)`, I got it off google and it works, but I'm unsure why.